# How to partition raw data values over 31 days according to 1 minute time intervals?

Tags: r, dataset, time-series

We have a data set that looks like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
...
```

In total we have 31 days worth of values over a 1 minute interval = 31*24*60 = 44640 total values.

We have loaded these values into a variable as follows:

`myData <- scan("file.txt")`

Now we are trying to partition the values using `ts()` such that these 1 minute intervals are recognized and we can plot the data accordingly. However, we fail in doing so since the current plot looks very ugly and chaotic -- doesn't make any sense. Any ideas on how to partition the values according the 1 minute time intervals?

Answer (score 0):

What about aggregating the values:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  x = seq(Sys.time(), Sys.time()+31*24*60*60-1, by = "1 min"),
  y = runif(31*24*60)
)
head(df)
#                     x         y
# 1 2016-07-06 22:17:50 0.2655087
# 2 2016-07-06 22:18:50 0.3721239
# 3 2016-07-06 22:19:50 0.5728534
# 4 2016-07-06 22:20:50 0.9082078
# 5 2016-07-06 22:21:50 0.2016819
# 6 2016-07-06 22:22:50 0.8983897
library(xts)
xts <- as.xts(df$y, df$x)

par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot(xts)
plot(apply.daily(xts, mean))
```

[image]